What is the correct module naming convention for an AWS lambda function in a Docker container?
The Dockerfile for the lambda container has this
# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "service.lambda_function.lambda_handler" ]

The Docker container directory contents include
function
       --__init__.py
       --service
           -- __init__.py
           -- lambda_function.py
                   def lambda_handler():
                        # do something 

When invoking the service we end up with:
LAMBDA_WARNING: Unhandled exception. 
The most likely cause is an issue in the function code. 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
Unable to import module 'service.lambda_function': No module named 'service'

But then why is the service module not found when invoking the lambda function?
Update
I have also tried putting the lambda_function.py directly underneath the function directory and changing the Dockerfile entry to:
CMD [ "lambda_function.lambda_handler" ].
That does not work either:

"Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'lambda_function'"

Another update
I also tried adding
WORKDIR /function

That did not change the result: we still get "No module named 'service'`
Here is the entire Dockerfile
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.12
COPY requirements.txt ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY function/ ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/function/
RUN ls -ltra ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
WORKDIR /function
CMD [ "lambda_function.lambda_handler" ]

